# creating a compound powershell object

Tags: powershell, object

I need to create a powershell object that will look like this:

```
 release
            windows
                test1 {testName;passRate}
                test2 {testName;passRate}
                test3 {testName;passRate}
                .
                .
            Linux
                test1 {testName;passRate}
                test2 {testName;passRate}
                test3 {testName;passRate}
                .
                .
        Trunk
            windows
                test1 {testName;passRate}
                test2 {testName;passRate}
                test3 {testName;passRate}
                .
                .
            Linux
                test1 {testName;passRate}
                test2 {testName;passRate}
                test3 {testName;passRate}
                .
                .
```

the "Release, Trunk, windows and Linux" are static. the tests are dynamic, meaning I'll be adding tests.

Does anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: What does the existing input/data look like?

Comment: right now I have only the tests (which have many properties but I'll use only the name and pass rate for this)

Comment: Do you mean you want some sort of textual template which is easy to maintain and easy to convert to a PS object?

Comment: I need an object I can add tests to it (let's say tests with pass rate lower than 50%) and then maybe turn it into a JSON file.

Comment: something like: release.windows.add(testname,passrate) or release.windows+=$test (where $test is an object that has the name and pass rate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after something like this?

```
$WinReleaseTest1 = @{
    Name = 'WinTest1'
    PassRate = 34
}
$WinReleaseTest2 = @{
    Name = 'WinTest2'
    PassRate = 56
}
$LinuxReleaseTest1 = @{
    Name = 'LinuxTest1'
    PassRate = 12
}
$LinuxReleaseTest2 = @{
    Name = 'LinuxTest2'
    PassRate = 75
}
$WinTrunkTest1 = @{
    Name = 'WinTest1'
    PassRate = 75
}
$WinTrunkTest2 = @{
    Name = 'WinTest2'
    PassRate = 6
}
$LinuxTrunkTest1 = @{
    Name = 'LinuxTest1'
    PassRate = 64
}
$LinuxTrunkTest2 = @{
    Name = 'LinuxTest2'
    PassRate = 32
}
$AllWinReleaseTests = Get-Variable -Name WinReleaseTest* -ValueOnly
$AllLinuxReleaseTests = Get-Variable -Name LinuxReleaseTest* -ValueOnly
$AllWinTrunkTests = Get-Variable -Name WinTrunkTest* -ValueOnly
$AllLinuxTrunkTests = Get-Variable -Name LinuxTrunkTest* -ValueOnly

$TestSummary = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Release = @{
        Windows = @{
        }
        Linux = @{
        }
    }
    Trunk = @{
        Windows = @{
        }
        Linux = @{
        }
    }
}

foreach ($Test in $AllLinuxReleaseTests) {
    $TestSummary.Release.Linux.Add($Test.Name,$Test.PassRate)
}
foreach ($Test in $AllWinReleaseTests) {
    $TestSummary.Release.Windows.Add($Test.Name,$Test.PassRate)
}
foreach ($Test in $AllLinuxTrunkTests) {
    $TestSummary.Trunk.Linux.Add($Test.Name,$Test.PassRate)
}
foreach ($Test in $AllWinTrunkTests) {
    $TestSummary.Trunk.Windows.Add($Test.Name,$Test.PassRate)
}
$TestSummary | ConvertTo-Json
```

Output:

```
{
"Release": {
    "Windows": {
    "WinTest2": 56,
    "WinTest1": 34
    },
    "Linux": {
    "LinuxTest1": 12,
    "LinuxTest2": 75
    }
},
"Trunk": {
    "Windows": {
    "WinTest2": 6,
    "WinTest1": 75
    },
    "Linux": {
    "LinuxTest1": 64,
    "LinuxTest2": 32
    }
  }
}
```